# Separating starting digits with regex

Tags: regex, preg-match

I want to separate the starting digits from strings as

```
01.text
2 - something
3 more
```

to get

```
array (
[0] => 01.text
[1] => 01
[2] text
)
array (
[0] => 2 - something
[1] => 2
[2] something
)
array (
[0] => 3 more
[1] => 3
[2] more
)
```

I tried a regex pattern of

```
^(\d+)\.+|\s+|-+(.*?)
```

but doesn't work as I expected.

*My problem is how to match `.` or `-` with or without space after the digits.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex uses an alternation which would match either in a capturing group one or more digits followed by a dot or a whitespace character or `|` in a group any character zero or more times non greedy.

You could update your regex to not use the alternations `|` and make the quantifier in the second group greedy.

In the first group capture one or more digits, then match your character in a character class  followed by another capturing group that would match one or more times any character:

[`^(\d+)[.\s-]+(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/vZ2kFU/3)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ci2Z3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It should match other cases too like ` - `,`-`. In other words, the separator between the digits and text can be either `-`,`\s`,`.` or all together.

Answer (score 1):

It's better try to give a pattern to strings that you want to split. I know that sometimes its not possible. So, this Regex match with all cases and give to you the Array you desire

`/^(\d+)[\.\-\s]*(.*)?$/`

```js
let rows = [
  "01.text",
  "2 - something",
  "3 more"
];
let regex = /^(\d+)[\.\-\s]*(.*)?$/;

for(let row of rows) {
  console.log(regex.exec(row))
}
```

Anyway, if you know more separators in the file add then to the [\.\-\s]*